vine copula parameters relation
I want to simulate from a trivariate vine copula where all the fitted pairs are frank copula with the same parameter =5, the question is Is it reasonable to simulate from vine copula that all pairs have the same parameter? and if not, what is the reasonable way to make all the paris have high kendall values ?
Ive tried in R it was working technicaly but not sure if it correct theoritcally.

One benefit of using the Vine Copula model over the Copula model is its flexibility in fitting different copula types for each pair of variables. Hence, the dependency parameters do not need to be the same across all the variables, which is the case for most real applications. Copula models, however, restrict the kind of dependency to single or mixture copulas that are the same for all the variables (the same as what you try to do). So, you can use a copula instead of a vine copula model to fit only a single type. Therefore, using a vine copula (computationally expensive) does not make sense when you need to model all your variables using only fixed type and dependency parameters. So, it is theoretically correct but not the best choice.
